# How to format CSV file into XLSX with correct spacing?

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

So I have a PowerShell Script that takes a CSV file with data inputted from sensors, and converts it into an Excel sheet and then prints it. My problem is that I can not get the format of the Excel sheet to be able to have the width of all my columns fit onto one page. I can have as many portrait pages as I want, but I need all columns to fit on one page.

I have tried: Ranges, Making things bold or not, and using the auto resize feature. None have worked.

```
$delimiter = ","
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $csv)
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $delimiter
$query.TextFileParseType  = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,1 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

# Execute & delete the import query
$query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()

#Green blocks if number passes
for($i=6;$i -le 84;$i++){
    if($worksheet.Cells.Item($i,6).value2 -match "True"){
        $Worksheet.Cells($i,4).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    }
    if($worksheet.Cells.Item($i,6).value2 -match "False"){
        $Worksheet.Cells($i,4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    }
}

$name1 = $worksheet.Cells.Item(1,6).Text
$name2 = $worksheet.Cells.Item(1,4).Text

# Formatting
$RangeBold = $Worksheet.Range("A1","C92")
$RangeBold.Select()
$RangeBold.Font.Bold=$True
$RangeBold = $Worksheet.Range("E1","E92")
$RangeBold.Select()
$RangeBold.Font.Bold=$True

$RangeDel = $Worksheet.Range("F1","F92")
$RangeDel.Select()
$RangeDel.Delete()

$RangeBorder = $Worksheet.Range("A1","E86")
$RangeBorder.Select()
$RangeBorder.Borders.LineStyle = 1
$RangeBorder.Borders.Weight = 2

# Footer Margin
worksheet("Sheet1").PageSetup.FooterMargin = _ 
 Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)

# Header Margin
Worksheet("Sheet1").PageSetup.HeaderMargin = _ 
 Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)

# Left Margin
Worksheet("Sheet1").PageSetup.LeftMargin = _ 
 Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)

# Right Margin
Worksheet("Sheet1").PageSetup.RightMargin = _ 
 Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)

$xlsx = "C:\ProgramData\CODESYS\CODESYSHMIWinV3\D5050FE1\PlcLogic\data\$name1-$name2.xlsx"




#Printing Excel Sheet
$xlsx.Visible = $true

$workbook = $xlsx.Workbooks.Open('C:\ProgramData\CODESYS\CODESYSHMIWinV3\D5050FE1\PlcLogic\data\$name1-$name2.xlsx')
$worksheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.Item(1)

$xlsx.ActivePrinter = "808_TOSHIBA5508A on WINFPS01.tld-america.com"

$worksheet.PrintOut(1,4,1)
$xlsx.quit()

# Save & close the Workbook as XLSX.
$Workbook.SaveAs($xlsx,51)

$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open($xlsx)
$excel.Quit()
Remove-Item $csv
Invoke-Item $xlsx
```

The sheet still prints with this code, just not formatted how I would like. I need the margins to be smaller, and wanted to center the text in each cell. Any thoughts or other resources to used? I have been google searching for hours and am not finding anything.

Comment: As this question is only vaguely relevant for Codesys programming, I think you will attract more answers if you change the tag to e.g. Excel, Powercell and CSV.

Comment: See [PageSetup.FitToPagesWide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.fittopageswide)